# Python-Updating an Array Permanently After Calling it in a Function

Tags: python, arrays

I have a question about how to update a string within a function after calling it. I want it to save after I call the function. It's the equivalent of pressing "control+s" to save an excel file after you edit it. Here's example code:

```
def function():
    x=['string'];y=input();x.append(y)
```

What I want have have happen is: If I call this function 3 times over a month, I'd like to have it read: x=['string',input1,input2,input3]

It currently will only store x 2 values maximum. For example: x=['string',input1]

I understand that even if there is a way to update this string/function, the fact that I have x=['string'] at the start will always change x to x=['string'] when I call it...Is there a built-in way to do this and have it update the way I want it to?

Comment: Write the list to a file and then read from it?

Comment: @jonrsharpe I have a list with thousands of values. Every time call a value in this list, I want to add it to another list and then delete it from the current list. So there would be an "Unused" list and a "Used" list.

Comment: @jonrsharpe you're right, I should use pop. And yes the program would restart. I just want to be able to update the list after I call the function every time. Is this possible without a database or excel sheet?

Comment: @jonrsharpe What do you recommend?

Comment: @jonrsharpe I'm not sure where to do research without accidentally stumbling on the answer. Is there a specific place you know of that would have this answer?

Comment: @jonrsharpe .......it's like if I asked you where nearest city was and you told me that I had to drive to it. Even if I got a general direction from you(n,s,e,w) it would help a lot.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I was just looking for some sort of a guide to find the answer. There's not need to be mean about it. If you don't know, just say you don't know.

Comment: @jonrsharpe This is an internet forum designed to help people with programming issues, so me asking if you know of a guide is reasonable. And how is this your living room? It's not your website.

Comment: Stack Overflow **is not a forum**. Please take the [tour], and brush up on [ask]. I see no point in continuing this discussion any further.

Comment: @AnandSKumar I'll be trying to get this method to work. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Store the x in a class or a closure. You also might want to return x or you won't be able to retrieve its values:

```
def foo():
    x = []
    def bar():
        y = input()
        x.append(y)
        return x
    return bar

b = foo()

# usage
In [8]: b()
aaa
Out[8]: ['aaa']

In [9]: b()
bbb
Out[9]: ['aaa', 'bbb']

In [10]: b()
ccc
Out[10]: ['aaa', 'bbb', 'ccc']
```